C# ASP.NET MVC web app - update view after completion of asynch calls w/ OpenAI
I have an ASP.NET MVC app in C# that I'm trying to asynchronously call a bunch of OpenAI requests in parallel and then wait on all results to return.
The following is a snippet from this code:
        foreach (ChatMessage msg in messages)
        {
            List<ChatMessage> tmpMessage = new List<ChatMessage>();
            tmpMessage.Add(msg);

            Task<ClientResult<ChatCompletion>> chatResult = client.CompleteChatAsync(tmpMessage, chatOptions);

            await chatResult;

            if (chatResult.IsCompleted && chatResult.Result.Value != null)
            {
                output.Add(chatResult.Result.Value.Content[0].Text);
            }
        }

Each string in the output list is a json structured output from OpenAI. I then go through each json output and manipulate it as needed.
My questions are: Is this truly asynchronous? I call the CompleteChatAsync but then I use await chatResult and I am uncertain if this is the way to do that asynchronously?
Second - the view portion of the webpage does not update once all results return and are processed. It just sits there. How do I refresh the view in the ASP.NET MVC web app in .NET?
Thanks!

it's asynchronous in the sense that await chatResult; does not block the current thread. This is important for instance in a GUI handler (a graphical event in a window), this means the window will not "freeze" until it's over. Or in a server, it will not "eat" a thread for other requests. However, the execution order is still synchronous, i.e. this particular code waits ("await") for the task to be over before continuing to the next step, like for synchronous code. Maybe you want to run all the tasks "concurrently" (fire them all then aggregate the results when all are terminated?).

Yes I'd like to fire all then aggregate but am not certain how to do that.

just on the pure task handling, you can create a var  allChatResults = new List<Task<ClientResult<ChatCompletion>>>() ;, then do a first  loop where you add the tasks to the list. Do not await or do anything. Once you have your list of Task ready, use await Task.WhenAll(allChatResults);. Then you can do a second loop over this list to examine and handle the results.

however, i've no idea right now why you don't see any output. You should start by debugging (breakpoints and/or print to console) and examine if there is actually data in the responses.

That worked perfectly - I was able to send all then batch them. When using .Wait() instead of await this loads the view appropriately but using await the view loads initially but then the data does not refresh the view once all tasks are complete. May just have to go with .Wait() instead of await.

Nice, glad to help, I've written a proper answer. About the Wait: I suspect the Tasks are "cold", i.e. they are not actually fired. You should not have to use ".Wait()", as this is completely synchronous and not recommended (this blocks the execution thread). Checking for an alternative on my side if I can

Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

could you try:
await Task.WhenAll(allChatResults).ConfigureAwait(true); for step 2 ?

To run several tasks "in parallel" (more correctly: concurrently), you can use Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks). The steps will be as follow:

Create the list of tasks (without awaiting them)
Fire them and wait for all of them to finish.
Handle the results.

example:
// Step 1
var allChatResults = new List<Task<ClientResult<ChatCompletion>>>();
foreach (ChatMessage msg in messages)
{
    var chatResult = client.CompleteChatAsync(tmpMessage, chatOptions);
    allChatResults.Add(chatResult);
}

// Step 2
await Task.WhenAll(allChatResults);

// Step 3
foreach (Task chatResult in allChatResults)
{
    if (chatResult.IsCompleted && chatResult.Result.Value != null)
    {
        output.Add(chatResult.Result.Value.Content[0].Text);
    }
}

